# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) Ruby

Tags: ruby

> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1).

The code opens the file and looks at the paragraph and counts, the error
 is in the center of the code. An error occurs when a method is called(1).
 I can’t understand how to pass the argument methods.

```
@books = "You can use this knowledge to create small tools that might help."

require "colorize"

class Filecalculation

    def select
        loop do
            puts "# Will we search : calculation_lines paragraph(1)".cyan
            print "\n>>>>>> ".yellow

            input = gets.chomp
            search_method = "calc_#{input}"
            if (respond_to?(search_method))
```

I can’t understand how to pass the argument to this place.

```
                contents = send(search_method, @books)
            else
                puts "Unknown input: #{input.inspect}, method #{search_method} not defined."
            end 
       end 
    end  

    # =================== calc_1 сounting words in Text File 
    def calc_1 paragraph            
        word_count = paragraph.split.length 
        puts "#{word_count} words"   
    end
end

Filecalculation.new.select
```

Comment: Please, make sure to construct a [mre]. Your example is far from minimal. In fact, your example can be condensed to two lines of code easily: `def foo(arg) end; send(:foo)`.

Comment: Ok, ok i cut a little

Comment: Forcing someone to read through 72 lines of irrelevant code when only 2 lines are relevant is the *exact opposite* of making it clear. It completely hides and obscures the problem.

Comment: Still reduced, yes but I wanted to show what the program does, what it transmits and what it receives

Comment: But all of that is completely irrelevant to your question, which is essentially "How do I pass arguments to `send`", and thus it just *noise* that makes it harder to understand, harder to debug, and harder to answer. Especially, since there are *other* bugs in your code that have absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with your question but *may* lead an answerer down a completely wrong path. Worse: those additional bugs make it *impossible* to run your code to verify that the problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks for the instructions.

Comment: 72 =>35 line code! making progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `send(search_method)` you call a method without arguments. To pass arguments to the method being called, you need to pass them as next `send` args:

```
send(search_method, arg1, arg2)
```

in your case

```
send(search_method, paragraph)
```

[Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Object.html#method-i-send)

Comment: error undefined methods .each_line ,  .scan,  .each_char, .each_line for Nil class

Comment: when I choose any option 1...2...3...4

Comment: try `send(search_method, @paragraph)` - you need to pass the variable that holds the paragraph string